# Rails is not deleting a cache/.html page when the sweeper is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sweeper

I'm having some issues with Sweepers and Caching in Rails.

The .html file in /cache is being generated on first view.

The Sweeper action is being called when needed.

However, the sweeper action is not deleting the .html page from /cache

The code below is stripped down from my /controllers and /sweepers directory.  the `puts` lines both log, so I know that we're executing fine -- the expire command just doesn't seem to delete the file.

anyone have an idea where i can lool ?

```
class WidgetsController < ApplicationController
    cache_sweeper :widget_sweeper
    caches_page :help
    def help
        render :template => '/widgets/help.html'
    end
end

class WidgetSweeper < ActionController::Caching::Sweeper
    observe HelpPage
    def after_save(record)
        puts "record "
        puts record.inspect
        expire_page(:controller => 'widgets', :action => 'help') 
        puts "ok!"
    end
end
```

Comment: I think it's a bit weird: you're supposed to observe a model,your model is named HelpPage?

Comment: I renamed the model and some elements to be more clear.  I just wanted to illustrate that i get to after_save, but the expire_page doesn't work.  i've also tried expire_page('/widgets/help')

Comment: Are there any parameters that are passed to the HTML page? For example /widgets/help?param=234? Also, have you verified that the cached page is stored as widgets/help.html and not under some other name?

Comment: I had to write expire_page(:controller => '/widgets', :action => 'help') in one of my websites because of namespacing (notice the '/'). Is it a track?

Answer (score 0):

Are you just testing this by manipulating some HelpPage records in the console?  It looks like you have to affect the changes in a controller.

I made a test app using the code you supplied above and ran it with caching enabled.  I created some new HelpPage records in the rails console, and I got the two log messages but no page expiration.

However, when I created a new HelpPage in a controller, I did get the page expiration as expected.